# What is this called in the context of Java Server Pages?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

What is the proper term to refer to this in the context of JSPs?

`${}`

`${some-bound-variable}`

What do you call the dollar sign followed by brackets containing a variable?

I am looking for the correct term because I am trying to figure out why mine are not working and I don't even know the correct term for them to google.

TIA

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm

Comment: "Value expression". See the [documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el003.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real name of that syntax Expression Language. You will often see it written as "EL expression" or just "EL".

But for googling I also do a search using the "jstl" term which is the standard taglib  but as both are really much use together, I often find more answers in that way than with the first term.